# Update mongodb positional field with another positional field passed as parameter into momentjs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, momentjs

I'm trying to update all documents in an array. I looked into positional operator $[], but the issue is I'm trying to update the field with the previous value passed to date library momentjs.
The query I tried and failed is

```
 await collection.update(
  {},
  {
    $set: {
      'activities.$[].duration.startTime': moment(
        'activities.$[].duration.startTime',
        'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss',
      ).toISOString(),
    },
  },
  { multi: true },
);
```

This sets `startTime` field as null. So my question is how can I pass the existing value of `activities.$[].duration.startTime` to moment function.

Sample document(Existing)

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "6030b9244991b3001c678492"
},
"activities": [{
    "effort": null,
    "duration": {
        "startTime": "19/01/2021 20:11:35",
        "endTime": "19/01/2021 20:15:15",
    },
}],
"userId": "5fc8c7504b26e66f676ea50d",
"workoutPlanCode": "",
```

}

Expected Output:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "6030b9244991b3001c678492"
},
"activities": [{
    "effort": null,
    "duration": {
        "startTime": "2021-01-19T20:58:49.010Z",
        "endTime": "2021-01-19T20:58:49.010Z",
    },
}],
"userId": "5fc8c7504b26e66f676ea50d",
"workoutPlanCode": "",
```

}

Comment: Could you confirm you realise momentjs module is installed on your nodejs application server and the update is executed on the mongodb server?

Comment: @AlexBlex yes, but if I want to use custom function in $set how can I do that?

Comment: You cannot. Nobody can.

Comment: Just to make it crystal clear, you are using relatively new update with aggregation operators. There are no npm packages there, not even vanilla javascript. You can use [these operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) only.  If you are trying to convert Date field to a string,  $dateToString should do the job.

Comment: @Totoro add your sample data query https://mongoplayground.net/ and update the story with the link. Also, add expected output.

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar added the existing document and expected output.

Comment: @AlexBlex In my existing documents date format is messed up so I want to convert it to ISO string. That's the reason I want to use moment in my migration script

Comment: Ah, now it makes more sense. Use $dateFromString followed by $dateToString to change format of the string. There is no chance to use momentjs without downloading data to app layer.

Comment: @Totoro is this 1-time activity to convert dates for existing records?

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar yes, 1 time activity only

Comment: @AlexBlex If you make your comment as an answer that would be helpful. I tried to do $dateFromString with $set and positional operator $[] but facing error.

Comment: Sorry forgot to comment on that bit. You need to use $map to $set whole array, but you made the point. Error handling is not straightforward and indeed deserves a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first - there is no way to use momentjs library and javascript in general in the update statement.

It is possible to update a field with value calculated from document itself using [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) available from v4.2.

To update items in an array you need to use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to iterate and update individual subdocuments.

Finally, specific to this question, some functionality of moment can be implemented using  [date expression operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-expression-operators).

The whole query would be:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "activities": {
        "$map": {
          input: "$activities",
          as: "a",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$a",
              {
                duration: {
                  startTime: {
                    $dateToString: {
                      date: {
                        $dateFromString: {
                          dateString: "$$a.duration.startTime",
                          format: "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S",
                          onError: null
                        }
                      },
                      format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z",
                      onNull: "$$a.duration.startTime"
                    }
                  },
                  endTime: {
                    $dateToString: {
                      date: {
                        $dateFromString: {
                          dateString: "$$a.duration.endTime",
                          format: "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S",
                          onError: null
                        }
                      },
                      format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z",
                      onNull: "$$a.duration.endTime"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  "multi": true
})
```

Things to bear in mind:

- Conversion from string to date may go wrong if the string is malformed or is in unexpected format. In this case the original string is preserved.
- Original date has no timezone, assumed UTC
- Original date has no milliseconds, assumed 000
- It is advisable to keep dates as dates in the database and convert to strings on the representation layer.

Comment: why do we need to map if there is positional operator https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#up._S_[]

Comment: It's for regular updates where you use constant `value`. It is tightly coupled with filter part (the first argument of update) and is not a thing in aggregation updates. Did you notice the second argument of the update is an array? Please read the documentation behind the links I put in the answer. It wouldn't bother to search the links if it wasn't important.

Answer (score 1):

This is 1-time activity is mentioned by OP.

Run this query from shell or Robomongo

[forEach](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#cursor.forEach)

[toArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/)

Perform find query filter records where `activities` are there, get a cursor and convert to toArray, loop over the records check if `startTime` is there convert it to date.

```
function convertToDate (date) {
    if (!date.split || date.split('/') < 1) return date; //  if it's already date type ignore.
    date = date.split('/');
                var month = date[1];
                var day = date[0]
                date[0] = month;
                date[1] = day;
    return new Date(date);
}

db.data2.find({ activities: { $exists: true } }).toArray().forEach(function (doc) {
    doc.activities.forEach(function (d) {
        if (d.duration) {
            if (d.duration.startTime) {
                d.duration.startTime = convertToDate(d.duration.startTime);  
            }
            if (d.duration.endTime) {
                d.duration.endTime = convertToDate(d.duration.endTime);  
            }
        }
    });
    // print(doc); // to validate just perform print and comment save part
    db.data2.save(doc); // save the document back
});
```